# Pass option value from one function to another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function like this:

```
  $('input[type=radio][name=editList]').change(function() {
                    if (this.value == 'Proveedor') {
                        $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetProveedores", "Agenda")",
                            function (data) {
                                var items = "";
                                $.each(data,
                                    function(index, item) {
                                        items += "<option value='" + item.ID + "'>" +item.ID+item.NombreComercial + "</option>";
                                    });
                                $("#lstProveedor").html(items);
                            });
```

I want to get that item.ID to use into another function as:

```
 $(function getCuadrilla() {
    var items = "";
   $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetCuadrillas", "Agenda")" + "?ProveedorID=" + ID, function (data) {

   $.each(data, function (index, item) {...

                            });
                            $("#lstcuadrilla").html(items);
                        });

                    });
```

I try to use `$('input[type=radio][name=editList]').val()` as

```
    $(function getCuadrilla() {
            var items = "";
$('input[type=radio][name=editList]').val();
 $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetCuadrillas", "Agenda")" + "?ProveedorID=" + ID, function (data) {

           $.each(data, function (index, item) {...

                                    });
                                    $("#lstcuadrilla").html(items);
                                });

                            });
```

but instead `item.ID` I receive string `"Proveedor"`, can any one explain me how can I access to item.ID? Regards

**Complete JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">


  $(function getResponsable() {
    $('input[type=radio][name=editList]')
      .change(function() {
        if (this.value == 'Proveedor') {
          $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetProveedores ", "Agenda ")",
            function(data) {
              var items = "";
              $.each(data,
                function(index, item) {
                  items += "<option value='" + item.ID + "'>" + item.ID + item.NombreComercial + "</option>";
                });
              $("#lstProveedor").html(items);
            });
        } else if (this.value == 'Sucursal') {
          $.getJSON("@Url.Action("
            GetUnidades ", "
            Agenda ")",
            function(data) {
              var items = "";
              $.each(data,
                function(index, item) {
                  items += "<option value='" + item.ID + "'>" + item.Codigo + "-" + item.Nombre + "</option>";
                });
              $("#lstProveedor").html(items);
            });

        } else if (this.value == 'Usuario') {
          $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetUsuario ", "Agenda ")",
            function(data) {
              var items = "";
              $.each(data,
                function(index, item) {
                  items += "<option value='" + item.ID + "'>" + item.Nombre + " " + item.Apellido + "</option>";
                });
              $("#lstProveedor").html(items);
            });
        }
      });

    $(function getCuadrilla() {
      var items = "";
     var ID = $("#lstProveedor").val();
      $.getJSON("@Url.Action(" GetCuadrillas ", "Agenda ")" + "ProveedorID=" + ID,
        function(data) {

          $.each(data, function(index, item) {
            items += "<option value='" + item.ID + "'>" + item.NombreComercial + "</option>";
          });
          $("#lstProveedor").html(items);
        });

    });

  });
```

As James comment, I try it and JS hit first line but it don´t pass over there 
[image]

Update:

**New js structure:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function getResponsable() {
            $('input[type=radio][name=editList]')
                .change(function() {
                    if (this.value == 'Proveedor') {
                        $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetProveedores", "Agenda")",
                            function(data) {
                                var items = "";
                                $.each(data,
                                    function(index, item) {
                                        items += "<option value='" +
                                            item.ID +
                                            "'>" +
                                            item.ID +
                                            item.NombreComercial +
                                            "</option>";
                                    });
                                $("#lstProveedor").html(items);
                            });
                    } else if (this.value == 'Sucursal') {
                        $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetUnidades", "Agenda")",
                            function(data) {
                                var items = "";
                                $.each(data,
                                    function(index, item) {
                                        items += "<option value='" +
                                            item.ID +
                                            "'>" +
                                            item.Codigo +
                                            "-" +
                                            item.Nombre +
                                            "</option>";
                                    });
                                $("#lstProveedor").html(items);
                            });

                    } else if (this.value == 'Usuario') {
                        $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetUsuario", "Agenda")",
                            function(data) {
                                var items = "";
                                $.each(data,
                                    function(index, item) {
                                        items += "<option value='" +
                                            item.ID +
                                            "'>" +
                                            item.Nombre +
                                            " " +
                                            item.Apellido +
                                            "</option>";
                                    });
                                $("#lstProveedor").html(items);
                            });
                    }

                });
            $("#lstProveedor").change(function() {
                var items = "";
                var ID = $("#lstProveedor").val();
                $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetCuadrillas", "Agenda")" + "ProveedorID=" + ID,
                  function(data) {
                      $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                          items += "<option value='" + item.ID + "'>" + item.NombreComercial + "</option>";
                      });
                      $("#lstProveedor").html(items);
                  }
    );
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Is it the id of the selected `<option>` that gets appended to `#lstProveedor` that you want?  `$('#lstProveedor').val()`

Comment: This is a little confusing, but I think that you saved the item.ID in the `$("#lstProveedor")` element when you crated you dropdown. So you shoul try to access it on that same element not on `$('input[type=radio][name=editList]')`

Comment: I try it as:  `var ID = $("#lstProveedor").val();` but it comes null @MarkE

Comment: I try it as:  `var ID = $("#lstProveedor").val();` but it comes null @James

Comment: I update my question with complete js

Comment: I debug it, and in the firrst load it got undefined, but If I load again it run correclty

Comment: getCuadrilla gets run on document.ready, so there is no selected provider yet.  And it looks like you would use that provider ID to update the same dropdown that the provider ID comes from.  That seems strange, and I dont understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes, exactly as you say, It run well if I select another one and select again it. It load ID = 1, how can I solve this issue and load `getCuadrilla`  when provider ID come? @James

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.  Keep in mind that the ID you are passing to the handler function is either a provider id or a sucursal id or a usuario id, depending on which radio button populated the drop down the first time around.  Also this handler will remain on the dropdown even when it has been populated by Cuadrillas.

Change

```
$(function getCuadrilla() {
  var items = "";
 var ID = $("#lstProveedor").val();
  $.getJSON("@Url.Action(" GetCuadrillas ", "Agenda ")" + "ProveedorID=" + ID,
    function(data) {

      $.each(data, function(index, item) {
        items += "<option value='" + item.ID + "'>" + item.NombreComercial + "</option>";
      });
      $("#lstProveedor").html(items);
    });

});
```

to

```
$("#lstProveedor").change(function (e) {
  var items = "";
  var ID = $("#lstProveedor").val();
  $.getJSON("@Url.Action(" GetCuadrillas ", "Agenda ")" + "ProveedorID=" + ID,
    function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(index, item) {
        items += "<option value='" + item.ID + "'>" + item.NombreComercial + "</option>";
      });
      $("#lstProveedor").html(items);
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: it hits: `$("#lstProveedor").change(function (e) {` but it dont pass over there

Comment: I upload photo ijn my question, it his on first line but it don´t pass over there and chrome doesn´t show any errors

Comment: It wants to be outside of the getResponsable function.

Comment: I put outside it, and now it doesn´t hit it, I upload my js as I have now in my question